# How to find clearcase symlinks?

Tags: clearcase

Currently, I have to wait for a symlink error when updating a clearcase view.  I then take the name for the broken symlink and search for it specifically.

is there a way to find all broken symlinks, without necessarily knowing the name?

how to find one at a time:

- cleartool> `cd C:\cc_view\view_name\source_app`
- cleartool> `find -all -type l -name "missing.link.name" -nxname -print`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need a -all in your find query.
Broken symlink in a snapshot view update are element which are visible:

```
cleartool find . -type l -name "missing.link.name" -nxname -print
```

You can execute that command in a DOS session ("`cleartool find`", instead of a cleartool one "`cleartool> find`"): that allows you to redirect the result in a text file and parse the result.

The IBM article "[How to find broken (orphaned) Symlinks](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21601126)" can also help.

#### Cause

> User renamed the target, so the symbolic link is pointing to a non existing target.
>
> After the rename of the versioned target file (`a.doc -> a.docx`, done by ClearCase Explorer) I get the update error, that the `symlink a.doc` does not exist.
>
> Unable to resolve symlink "filename.doc". The symlink target will not be loaded.
>
> - Where can I find the link itself (in which folder is it located?)?
> - How can I solve the rename (?) of the symlink?

#### Answer

> To find and remove the symlink:
>
> - **Use a dynamic view (snapshot views cannot load the missing links)**.
> - Run `M:\viewtag\vobtag>cleartool find . -kind slink -print`
> - Refer to the following technote for information about how to remove the symlinks as found in the output of the above command: "[Unable to resolve VOB symlink](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21125166)":
>
> A cleartool ls from the command prompt will show:

```
virt.46e5e94ff9024144ab0fe9ed432ce6e6 --> ../virt
virt.5043bcc7c8f44439938d634bd5ba9ac2 --> ..virt [not loaded]
```

> The above symbolic link is to a resource outside of ClearCase, which renders the hyperlink invalid for use in UCM.

#### Resolving the problem

> Remove the broken (dangling) link from the VOB to clear the error, using the `cleartool rmname` command.
>
> Example:

```
cleartool rmname virt.46e5e94ff9024144ab0fe9ed432ce6e6
```

> Using `cleartool rmname` allows you to preserve the symbolic link, but remove references
>   to it from future directory versions.
>   Symbolic links can be permanently removed using `cleartool rmelem`, refer to [technote 1148781](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&rs=984&uid=swg21148781) for more details.

Comment: referenced on the IBM link in the answer [what to do with the output from the `find . -kind slink -print` output](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21125166)

Comment: @DefyGravity true: I have added the link and the relevant extract from that technote.

Comment: What is the difference between -kind slink and -type l?

Comment: @antred I don't think there are much differences if any. I am simply used to create symlink (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21260645) with `ln -slink`. To maintain coherency, I look for them with `-kind slink`. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425 uses `-type l` though.

Comment: @VonC Hmm, I just tried it out. Both variants actually do give very different results, though I haven't figured out exactly what the differences are yet.